# Overloading static class' static methods in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a typescript static class where I convert key pair values to string.
The key pair value can have boolean, number, string as values but in the end I want all of them to be converted to string (each have implementation specified by me).

```
[{ key: "key1", value: false },
 { key: "key2", value: "sample string"},
 { key: "key3", value: 55}]
```

This is what I have so far. But it is giving me the duplicate function implementation.
I want this key pair converter class so I can just loop throughout my list regardless of the value's type.

```
export abstract class KeyPair {
  public static toString(val: boolean): string {
    return (+val).toString();
  }

  public static toString(val: string): string {
    return val;
  }

  public static toString(val: number): string {
    return ""+val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TypeScript is just JavaScript under the hood, there are no overloads like you may be used to in other languages (just [overload *signatures*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)).

You'll want a single function that can accept an union of the three types and does the right thing internally.

```
export abstract class KeyPair {
  public static toString(val: boolean | string | number): string {
    if (typeof val === "boolean") return (+val).toString();
    if (typeof val === "string") return val;
    if (typeof val === "number") return String(val);
    throw new Error(`Can't convert ${val}`);
  }
}
```